# Convert a cURL request to Javascript for an API call using hashed Authentication

Tags: javascript, json, api, curl

I am a beginner at Javascript and APIs and I am trying to make PUT request with my credentials hashed with MD5 using Javascript which brings me back an Auth Code so that I can use to stay connected with the server but I haven't been able to.

I have a cURL request that does exactly what I need but I don't know how to make the same request from Javascript, I am using jQuery Ajax to try and do it.

my cURL code that works fine, looks like this:

```
curl -s -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data": {"credentials": "MY-HASHED-CREDENTIALS","account_name": "My-account","method": "md5"}}' -k https://my.domain.com:8443/v1/user_auth
```

And here is the Javascript version that brings back the error:

> 400 (Bad Request)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://my.domain.com:8443/v1/user_auth",
        headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
        data: {"credentials": "MY-HASHED-CREDENTIALS","account_name": "Centrecom","method": "md5"},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

I am open to suggestions on how to get this done in Javascript, either by translating the cURL or by using a library.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use postman to call API?

I tried to convert your curl command.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://my.domain.com:8443/v1/user_auth",
  "method": "PUT",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "d009277c-c4f9-5f49-a65f-83cd74436826"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\"credentials\": \"MY-HASHED-CREDENTIALS\",\"account_name\": \"Centrecom\",\"method\": \"md5\"}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Unfortunately, it didn't work, it returned the same error.